# Modbus Protocol RTU

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, c, modbus

I have simple code working on Serial Communication asn below. With Same data i would impliment Modbus protocol> I have Used Modbus library for arduino earlier which works fine with 9600 baudrate and wont work with higher baudrates.And also have restriction In library ,They directly storing values into Buffers SO i cant able to fig out weather request send proper or improper.
I never Worked on EMbeded c Chip level code.Is there any way to Implement without library for arduino

In below code I would Like Serial value into register and when function called i could read value. Similarly the **function CODE** for Modbus should be implemented.

I am looking for simple c code or implement c code Where i can perform the operation this way.

I am trying to Send modbus Request

I found CRC error calculation like in one of forum

```
 unsigned int crc_fn(unsigned char *dpacket,unsigned int len)    // CRC 16 Function(Error calculation)
    {
        unsigned int crc = 0xffff,poly = 0xa001;
        unsigned char i=0,j=0;

        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            crc^= dpacket[i];
            for(j=0;j<8;j++)
            {
                if(crc & 0x01)
                {
                    crc >>= 1;
                    crc ^= poly;
                }
                else
                crc >>= 1;
            }
        }
        return (crc);
    }
```

**I would like to See my code in arduino Like this With CRC check**

```
void Serial_access(void)
{
    unsigned char i=0,len=0,ser_data[60],crc_data[60],j=0;
    unsigned int crc1=0,crc2=0;
    crc1 = crc_fn(&rxbuf[0],6);
    _delay_ms(100);
    if((rxbuf[6] == (unsigned char)(crc1))&&(rxbuf[7] == (unsigned char)(crc1>>8)))
    {
        if(rxbuf[0]==DEVICE_ID)
        {
            if(rxbuf[1] == Function_code)
            {
                if((rxbuf[5]>=1)&&(rxbuf[5]<30))
                {
                    //Address = ((unsigned int)(rxbuf[2]<<8)+((unsigned int)(rxbuf[3])));
                    len = (rxbuf[5]*2);
                    _delay_ms(10);
                    ser_data[0] = 0;
                    ser_data[1] = 0;
                    ser_data[2] = 0;
                    ser_data[3] = 0;
                    ser_data[4] = 0;
                    ser_data[5] = 0;
                    ser_data[6] = 0;
                    ser_data[7] = 0;
                    ser_data[8] = 0;
                    ser_data[9] = 0;
                    ser_data[10] = 0;
                    ser_data[11] = 0;
                    ser_data[12] = 0;
                    ser_data[13] = 0;
                    ser_data[14] = 0;
                    ser_data[15] = 0;
                    ser_data[16] = 0;
                    ser_data[17] = 0;
                    ser_data[18] = 0;
                    ser_data[19] = 0;
                    ser_data[20] = 0;
                    ser_data[21] = 0;
                    ser_data[22] = 0;
                    ser_data[23] = 0;
                    ser_data[24] = 0;
                    ser_data[25] = 0;
                    ser_data[26] = 0;
                    ser_data[27] = 0;
                    ser_data[28] = 0;
                    ser_data[29] = 0;
                    ser_data[30] = 0;
                    ser_data[31] = 0;
                    ser_data[32] = 0;
                    ser_data[33] = 0;
                    ser_data[34] = 0;
                    ser_data[35] = 0;
                    ser_data[36] = 0;
                    ser_data[37] = 0;
                    ser_data[38] = 0;
                    ser_data[39] = 0;
                    ser_data[40] = 0;
                    ser_data[41] = 0;
                    ser_data[42] = 0;
                    ser_data[43] = 0;
                    ser_data[44] = 0;
                    ser_data[45] = 0;
                    ser_data[46] = 0;
                    ser_data[47] = 0;
                    ser_data[48] = 0;
                    ser_data[49] = 0;
                    ser_data[50] = 0;
                    ser_data[51] = 0;
                    ser_data[52] = 0;
                    ser_data[53] = 0;
                    ser_data[54] = 0;
                    ser_data[55] = 0;
                    ser_data[56] = 0;
                    ser_data[57] = 0;
                    ser_data[58] = 0;

                    crc_data[0] = DEVICE_ID;
                    crc_data[1] = Function_code;
                    crc_data[2] = len;

                    j=3;
                    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
                    {
                        crc_data[j++] = ser_data[i];
                    }
                    crc2 = crc_fn(&crc_data[0],(len+3));
                    _delay_ms(100);
                    serial_send(DEVICE_ID);
                    serial_send(Function_code);
                    serial_send(len);
                    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
                    {
                        serial_send(ser_data[i]);
                    }
                    _delay_ms(10);
                    serial_send((unsigned char)(crc2));
                    serial_send((unsigned char)(crc2>>8));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    index = 0;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        rxbuf[i] = 0;
    rec_flag = 0;
    check_flag = 1; 
}
```

Here code written in C++, How can we convert these to C

```
int8_t Modbus::query( modbus_t telegram ) {
  uint8_t u8regsno, u8bytesno;
  if (u8id != 0) return -2;
  if (u8state != COM_IDLE) return -1;

  if ((telegram.u8id == 0) || (telegram.u8id > 247)) return -3;

  au16regs = telegram.au16reg;

  // telegram header
  au8Buffer[ ID ]         = telegram.u8id;
  au8Buffer[ FUNC ]       = telegram.u8fct;
  au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ]     = highByte(telegram.u16RegAdd );
  au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ]     = lowByte( telegram.u16RegAdd );

  switch ( telegram.u8fct ) {
  case MB_FC_READ_COILS:
  case MB_FC_READ_DISCRETE_INPUT:
  case MB_FC_READ_REGISTERS:
  case MB_FC_READ_INPUT_REGISTER:
    au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]      = highByte(telegram.u16CoilsNo );
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]      = lowByte( telegram.u16CoilsNo );
    u8BufferSize = 6;
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_COIL:
    au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]      = ((au16regs[0] > 0) ? 0xff : 0);
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]      = 0;
    u8BufferSize = 6;
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER:
    au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]      = highByte(au16regs[0]);
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]      = lowByte(au16regs[0]);
    u8BufferSize = 6;
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_COILS:
    u8regsno = telegram.u16CoilsNo / 16;
    u8bytesno = u8regsno * 2;
    if ((telegram.u16CoilsNo % 16) != 0) {
      u8bytesno++;
      u8regsno++;
    }

    au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]      = highByte(telegram.u16CoilsNo );
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]      = lowByte( telegram.u16CoilsNo );
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO + 1 ]    = u8bytesno;
    u8BufferSize = 7;

    u8regsno = u8bytesno = 0; // now auxiliary registers
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < telegram.u16CoilsNo; i++) {


    }
    break;

  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS:
    au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]      = highByte(telegram.u16CoilsNo );
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]      = lowByte( telegram.u16CoilsNo );
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO + 1 ]    = (uint8_t) ( telegram.u16CoilsNo * 2 );
    u8BufferSize = 7;

    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < telegram.u16CoilsNo; i++) {
      au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = highByte( au16regs[ i ] );
      u8BufferSize++;
      au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = lowByte( au16regs[ i ] );
      u8BufferSize++;
    }
    break;
  }

  sendTxBuffer();
  u8state = COM_WAITING;
  return 0;
}

int8_t Modbus::poll() {
  // check if there is any incoming frame
  uint8_t u8current = port->available();

  if (millis() > u32timeOut) {
    u8state = COM_IDLE;
    u16errCnt++;
    return 0;
  }

  if (u8current == 0) return 0;

  // check T35 after frame end or still no frame end
  if (u8current != u8lastRec) {
    u8lastRec = u8current;
    u32time = millis() + T35;
    return 0;
  }
  if (millis() < u32time) return 0;

  // transfer Serial buffer frame to auBuffer
  u8lastRec = 0;
  int8_t i8state = getRxBuffer();
  if (i8state < 7) {
    u8state = COM_IDLE;
    u16errCnt++;
    return i8state;
  }

  // validate message: id, CRC, FCT, exception
  uint8_t u8exception = validateAnswer();
  if (u8exception != 0) {
    u8state = COM_IDLE;
    return u8exception;
  }

  // process answer
  switch ( au8Buffer[ FUNC ] ) {
  case MB_FC_READ_COILS:
  case MB_FC_READ_DISCRETE_INPUT:
    // call get_FC1 to transfer the incoming message to au16regs buffer
   // get_FC1( );
    break;
  case MB_FC_READ_INPUT_REGISTER:
  case MB_FC_READ_REGISTERS :
    // call get_FC3 to transfer the incoming message to au16regs buffer
    get_FC3( );
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_COIL:
  case MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER :
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_COILS:
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS :
    // nothing to do
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
  u8state = COM_IDLE;
  return u8BufferSize;
}


int8_t Modbus::poll( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {

  au16regs = regs;
  u8regsize = u8size;

  // check if there is any incoming frame
  uint8_t u8current = port->available();
  if (u8current == 0) return 0;

  // check T35 after frame end or still no frame end
  if (u8current != u8lastRec) {
    u8lastRec = u8current;
    u32time = millis() + T35;
    return 0;
  }
  if (millis() < u32time) return 0;

  u8lastRec = 0;
  int8_t i8state = getRxBuffer();
  if (i8state < 7) return i8state;

  // check slave id
  if (au8Buffer[ ID ] != u8id) return 0;

  // validate message: CRC, FCT, address and size
  uint8_t u8exception = validateRequest();
  if (u8exception > 0) {
    if (u8exception != NO_REPLY) {
      buildException( u8exception );
      sendTxBuffer();
    }
    return u8exception;
  }

  u32timeOut = millis() + long(u16timeOut);

  // process message
  switch ( au8Buffer[ FUNC ] ) {
  case MB_FC_READ_COILS:
  case MB_FC_READ_DISCRETE_INPUT:
    return process_FC1( regs, u8size );
    break;
  case MB_FC_READ_INPUT_REGISTER:
  case MB_FC_READ_REGISTERS :
    return process_FC3( regs, u8size );
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_COIL:
    return process_FC5( regs, u8size );
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER :
    return process_FC6( regs, u8size );
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_COILS:
    return process_FC15( regs, u8size );
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS :
    return process_FC16( regs, u8size );
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
}

void Modbus::init(uint8_t u8id, uint8_t u8serno, uint8_t u8txenpin) {
  this->u8id = u8id;
  this->u8serno = (u8serno > 3) ? 0 : u8serno;
  this->u8txenpin = u8txenpin;
  this->u16timeOut = 1000;// intially set for 1000
}


int8_t Modbus::getRxBuffer() {
  boolean bBuffOverflow = false;

  if (u8txenpin > 1) digitalWrite( u8txenpin, LOW );

  u8BufferSize = 0;
  while ( port->available() ) {
    au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = port->read();
    u8BufferSize ++;

    if (u8BufferSize >= MAX_BUFFER) bBuffOverflow = true;
  }
  u16InCnt++;

  if (bBuffOverflow) {
    u16errCnt++;
    return ERR_BUFF_OVERFLOW;
  }
  u32timeOut=500;
   // u32timeOut = millis() + (unsigned long) u16timeOut;
  return u8BufferSize;
}


void Modbus::sendTxBuffer() {
  uint8_t i = 0;

  // append CRC to message
  uint16_t u16crc = calcCRC( u8BufferSize );
  au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = u16crc >> 8;
  u8BufferSize++;
  au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = u16crc & 0x00ff;
  u8BufferSize++;

  // set RS485 transceiver to transmit mode
  if (u8txenpin > 1) {
    switch ( u8serno ) {
#if defined(UBRR1H)
    case 1:
      UCSR1A = UCSR1A | (1 << TXC1);
      break;
#endif

#if defined(UBRR2H)
    case 2:
      UCSR2A = UCSR2A | (1 << TXC2);
      break;
#endif

#if defined(UBRR3H)
    case 3:
      UCSR3A = UCSR3A | (1 << TXC3);
      break;
#endif
    case 0:
    default:
      UCSR0A = UCSR0A | (1 << TXC0);
      break;
    }
    digitalWrite( u8txenpin, HIGH );
  }

  // transfer buffer to serial line
  port->write( au8Buffer, u8BufferSize );

  // keep RS485 transceiver in transmit mode as long as sending
  if (u8txenpin > 1) {
    switch ( u8serno ) {
#if defined(UBRR1H)
    case 1:
      while (!(UCSR1A & (1 << TXC1)));
      break;
#endif

#if defined(UBRR2H)
    case 2:
      while (!(UCSR2A & (1 << TXC2)));
      break;
#endif

#if defined(UBRR3H)
    case 3:
      while (!(UCSR3A & (1 << TXC3)));
      break;
#endif
    case 0:
    default:
      while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << TXC0)));
      break;
    }

    // return RS485 transceiver to receive mode
    digitalWrite( u8txenpin, LOW );
  }
  port->flush();
  u8BufferSize = 0;

  // set time-out for master
//  u32timeOut = millis() + (unsigned long) u16timeOut;
 u32timeOut=500;
  // increase message counter
  u16OutCnt++;
}



uint16_t Modbus::calcCRC(uint8_t u8length) {
  unsigned int temp, temp2, flag;
  temp = 0xFFFF;
  for (unsigned char i = 0; i < u8length; i++) {
    temp = temp ^ au8Buffer[i];
    for (unsigned char j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
      flag = temp & 0x0001;
      temp >>= 1;
      if (flag)
        temp ^= 0xA001;
    }
  }
  // Reverse byte order.
  temp2 = temp >> 8;
  temp = (temp << 8) | temp2;
  temp &= 0xFFFF;
  // the returned value is already swapped
  // crcLo byte is first & crcHi byte is last
  return temp;
}

uint8_t Modbus::validateRequest() {
  // check message crc vs calculated crc
  uint16_t u16MsgCRC =
    ((au8Buffer[u8BufferSize - 2] << 8)
    | au8Buffer[u8BufferSize - 1]); // combine the crc Low & High bytes
  if ( calcCRC( u8BufferSize - 2 ) != u16MsgCRC ) {
    u16errCnt ++;
    return NO_REPLY;
  }

  // check fct code
  boolean isSupported = false;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof( fctsupported ); i++) {
    if (fctsupported[i] == au8Buffer[FUNC]) {
      isSupported = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!isSupported) {
    u16errCnt ++;
    return EXC_FUNC_CODE;
  }

  // check start address & nb range
 // uint16_t u16regs = 4000;
 uint16_t u16regs = 0;
  uint8_t u8regs;
  switch ( au8Buffer[ FUNC ] ) {
  case MB_FC_READ_COILS:
  case MB_FC_READ_DISCRETE_INPUT:
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_COILS:
    u16regs = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ]) / 16;
    u16regs += word( au8Buffer[ NB_HI ], au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]) / 16;
    u8regs = (uint8_t) u16regs;
    if (u8regs > u8regsize) return EXC_ADDR_RANGE;
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_COIL:
    u16regs = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ]) / 16;
    u8regs = (uint8_t) u16regs;
    if (u8regs > u8regsize) return EXC_ADDR_RANGE;
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER :
    u16regs = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ]);
    u8regs = (uint8_t) u16regs;
    if (u8regs > u8regsize) return EXC_ADDR_RANGE;
    break;
  case MB_FC_READ_REGISTERS :
  case MB_FC_READ_INPUT_REGISTER :
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS :
    u16regs = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ]);
    u16regs += word( au8Buffer[ NB_HI ], au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]);
    u8regs = (uint8_t) u16regs;
    if (u8regs > u8regsize) return EXC_ADDR_RANGE;
    break;
  }
  return 0; // OK, no exception code thrown
}


uint8_t Modbus::validateAnswer() {
  // check message crc vs calculated crc
  uint16_t u16MsgCRC =
    ((au8Buffer[u8BufferSize - 2] << 8)
    | au8Buffer[u8BufferSize - 1]); // combine the crc Low & High bytes
  if ( calcCRC( u8BufferSize - 2 ) != u16MsgCRC ) {
    u16errCnt ++;
    return NO_REPLY;
  }

  // check exception
  if ((au8Buffer[ FUNC ] & 0x80) != 0) {
    u16errCnt ++;
    return ERR_EXCEPTION;
  }

  // check fct code
  boolean isSupported = false;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof( fctsupported ); i++) {
    if (fctsupported[i] == au8Buffer[FUNC]) {
      isSupported = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!isSupported) {
    u16errCnt ++;
    return EXC_FUNC_CODE;
  }

  return 0; // OK, no exception code thrown
}


void Modbus::buildException( uint8_t u8exception ) {
  uint8_t u8func = au8Buffer[ FUNC ];  // get the original FUNC code

  au8Buffer[ ID ]      = u8id;
  au8Buffer[ FUNC ]    = u8func + 0x80;
  au8Buffer[ 2 ]       = u8exception;
  u8BufferSize         = EXCEPTION_SIZE;
}
```

The functionality Check

```
void Modbus::get_FC3() {
  uint8_t u8byte, i;
  u8byte = 3;

  for (i = 0; i < au8Buffer[ 2 ] / 2; i++) {
    au16regs[ i ] = word(
    au8Buffer[ u8byte ],
    au8Buffer[ u8byte + 1 ]);
    u8byte += 2;
  }
}


int8_t Modbus::process_FC1( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {
  uint8_t u8currentRegister, u8currentBit, u8bytesno, u8bitsno;
  uint8_t u8CopyBufferSize;
  uint16_t u16currentCoil, u16coil;

  // get the first and last coil from the message
  uint16_t u16StartCoil = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ] );
  uint16_t u16Coilno = word( au8Buffer[ NB_HI ], au8Buffer[ NB_LO ] );

  // put the number of bytes in the outcoming message
  u8bytesno = (uint8_t) (u16Coilno / 8);
  if (u16Coilno % 8 != 0) u8bytesno ++;
  au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ]  = u8bytesno;
  u8BufferSize         = ADD_LO;

  // read each coil from the register map and put its value inside the outcoming message
  u8bitsno = 0;

  for (u16currentCoil = 0; u16currentCoil < u16Coilno; u16currentCoil++) {
    u16coil = u16StartCoil + u16currentCoil;
    u8currentRegister = (uint8_t) (u16coil / 16);
    u8currentBit = (uint8_t) (u16coil % 16);

    bitWrite(
    au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ],
    u8bitsno,
    bitRead( regs[ u8currentRegister ], u8currentBit ) );
    u8bitsno ++;

    if (u8bitsno > 7) {
      u8bitsno = 0;
      u8BufferSize++;
    }
  }

  // send outcoming message
  if (u16Coilno % 8 != 0) u8BufferSize ++;
  u8CopyBufferSize = u8BufferSize +2;
  sendTxBuffer();
  return u8CopyBufferSize;
}

int8_t Modbus::process_FC3( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {

  uint8_t u8StartAdd = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ] );
  uint8_t u8regsno = word( au8Buffer[ NB_HI ], au8Buffer[ NB_LO ] );
  uint8_t u8CopyBufferSize;
  uint8_t i;

  au8Buffer[ 2 ]       = u8regsno * 2;
  u8BufferSize         = 3;

  for (i = u8StartAdd; i < u8StartAdd + u8regsno; i++) {
    au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = highByte(regs[i]);
    u8BufferSize++;
    au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = lowByte(regs[i]);
    u8BufferSize++;
  }
  u8CopyBufferSize = u8BufferSize +2;
  sendTxBuffer();

  return u8CopyBufferSize;
}


int8_t Modbus::process_FC5( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {
  uint8_t u8currentRegister, u8currentBit;
  uint8_t u8CopyBufferSize;
  uint16_t u16coil = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ] );

  // point to the register and its bit
  u8currentRegister = (uint8_t) (u16coil / 16);
  u8currentBit = (uint8_t) (u16coil % 16);

  // write to coil
  bitWrite(
  regs[ u8currentRegister ],
  u8currentBit,
  au8Buffer[ NB_HI ] == 0xff );


  // send answer to master
  u8BufferSize = 6;
  u8CopyBufferSize = u8BufferSize +2;
  sendTxBuffer();

  return u8CopyBufferSize;

}


int8_t Modbus::process_FC6( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {

  uint8_t u8add = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ] );
  uint8_t u8CopyBufferSize;
  uint16_t u16val = word( au8Buffer[ NB_HI ], au8Buffer[ NB_LO ] );

  regs[ u8add ] = u16val;

  // keep the same header
  u8BufferSize         = RESPONSE_SIZE;

  u8CopyBufferSize = u8BufferSize +2;
  sendTxBuffer();

  return u8CopyBufferSize;
}


int8_t Modbus::process_FC15( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {
  uint8_t u8currentRegister, u8currentBit, u8frameByte, u8bitsno;
  uint8_t u8CopyBufferSize;
  uint16_t u16currentCoil, u16coil;
  boolean bTemp;

  // get the first and last coil from the message
  uint16_t u16StartCoil = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ] );
  uint16_t u16Coilno = word( au8Buffer[ NB_HI ], au8Buffer[ NB_LO ] );


  // read each coil from the register map and put its value inside the outcoming message
  u8bitsno = 0;
  u8frameByte = 7;
  for (u16currentCoil = 0; u16currentCoil < u16Coilno; u16currentCoil++) {

    u16coil = u16StartCoil + u16currentCoil;
    u8currentRegister = (uint8_t) (u16coil / 16);
    u8currentBit = (uint8_t) (u16coil % 16);

    bTemp = bitRead(
    au8Buffer[ u8frameByte ],
    u8bitsno );

    bitWrite(
    regs[ u8currentRegister ],
    u8currentBit,
    bTemp );

    u8bitsno ++;

    if (u8bitsno > 7) {
      u8bitsno = 0;
      u8frameByte++;
    }
  }

  // send outcoming message
  // it's just a copy of the incomping frame until 6th byte
  u8BufferSize         = 6;
  u8CopyBufferSize = u8BufferSize +2;
  sendTxBuffer();
  return u8CopyBufferSize;
}


int8_t Modbus::process_FC16( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {
  uint8_t u8func = au8Buffer[ FUNC ];  // get the original FUNC code
  uint8_t u8StartAdd = au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ] << 8 | au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ];
  uint8_t u8regsno = au8Buffer[ NB_HI ] << 8 | au8Buffer[ NB_LO ];
  uint8_t u8CopyBufferSize;
  uint8_t i;
  uint16_t temp;

  // build header
  au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]   = 0;
  au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]   = u8regsno;
  u8BufferSize         = RESPONSE_SIZE;

  // write registers
  for (i = 0; i < u8regsno; i++) {
    temp = word(
    au8Buffer[ (BYTE_CNT + 1) + i * 2 ],
    au8Buffer[ (BYTE_CNT + 2) + i * 2 ]);

    regs[ u8StartAdd + i ] = temp;
  }
  u8CopyBufferSize = u8BufferSize +2;
  sendTxBuffer();

  return u8CopyBufferSize;
}
```

Comment: several suggestions:  1) separate the code to write to the modbus from the code to read the modbus 2) use something like `select()` or `poll()` after writing to the modbus, then call the function to read the modbus. 3) modbus does not initiate communication, it only responds to commands (there are several different commands and your code does not allow for each command having variations in the format. )  4) the length of each command and response message can (and usually is) different.  5) do not send useless bytes (all those zeros).  5) (cont)

Comment: all modbus communication is a) command/request b) response.  Your code is not allowing for that

Comment: suggest setting up each command/request from separate functions and each of those separate functions call a serial write function, then select() then a serial read function.  During the read, need to check the `device id` to determine if response is to be ignored or not. Then check the response type to determine what to do (it may be an error response) then check the length to determine how many bytes still to read,  then read the data bytes and CRC, Then check the CRC to determine the validity of the message.

Comment: @user3629249 is there any example code written in C , to get send command and get response.The above code written in Embedded c . is there already code written for Atmega 328 or modbus functions.

Comment: The newly posted edit, the C++ code, can be changed to C by replacing all the `Modbus::` sequences with `modbus_`.   I did not note any other items that are specific to C++, however, the C++ code is assuming several definitions and structs are already setup, and available.

Comment: the use of the type: `boolean` means you will need the statement: `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: for ease of readability of the C++ code, 1) suggest the width of an indent be 4 spaces rather than just 2 spaces 2) separate the code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  3) the file name extension needs to be changed from `cpp` to `c`

Comment: @user3629249 Is there any code already written in C for mODBUS RTU

Comment: this may be of some help: `http://cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/149507-modbus-rtu-c-programming.html` for some code and here is the home web site for modbus: `http://www.modbus.org/tech.php` and here us some more sample code: `http://control.com/thread/1301963718`